# reverse string using for of in javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how this work, but the function below is fine. I'm confused, isn't the first iteration of for of loop print `h`? `h + '' = h`, how it got reversed?

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversed = ''
  for (let char of str) {
    reversed = char + reversed
  }
  return reversed
}

console.log(reverse('hello world'))
```

Comment: It starts with `h` to put it on the end.  Step through every iteration, you will see subsequent characters get put *in front* of previous ones; that's what the line `reversed = char + reversed` does

Comment: It doesn't print anything inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note : I am adding this answer just to help understand OP.**

So its fairly simple to understand if you add an `console.log()` inside the inner loop.
Basically `reversed = char + reversed;` here is what all logic is.

Lets try breaking it :

1) The inner loop begin with the first character of the string passed and the prepend it to existing local var `reversed` so its now `''+h` = 'h'

2) Now in second iteration we have `e`. so in loop we have 'h' and what happens is `h` = `e + h` which turn out to be `"eh"`

3) follow the same path and you have a reversed String... :D

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversed = ''
  for(let char of str){
    reversed = char + reversed;
    // add this line to understand how this works!
    console.log(reversed);
  }
  return reversed;
}

console.log(reverse('hello world'));
```

Comment: seems like an answer was already posted before i done posting..anyways cant help slow internet...lol

Answer (score 0):

In the `for-of` loop, `char` will be each character in order (so, `'h'`, then `'e'`, etc.). We start out with `reversed` set to `''` (a blank string). Then the body does this:

```
reversed = char + reversed;
```

So that takes whatever is in `reversed` and adds it to the end of `char`, then puts the result in `reversed`. So

- On the first loop, `char` is `'h'` and `reversed` is `''`, so `'h' + ''` is `'h'` and `'h'` is stored in `reversed`.
- On the second loop, `char` is `'e'` and `reversed` is `'h'`, so `'e' + 'h'` is `'eh'` and `'eh'` is stored in `reversed`.
- On the third loop, `char` is `'l'` and `reversed` is `'eh'`, so `'l' + 'eh'` is `'leh'` and `'leh'` is stored in `reversed`.

...and so on.

By far the best way to understand how this kind of thing works is to use the debugger built into your IDE or browser to set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and then step through it statement by statement. In most browsers, you can access the developer tools through <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, or the menus. Search for "(your browser here) dev tools" to find sites describing how to use the devtools in your brower, or "(your IDE here) debugger" for information about using the debugger in your IDE.

As very much **second-best** option, we can add `console.log` statements to see what's going on:

```js
function reverse(str) {
  let reversed = ''
  for (let char of str) {
    console.log("char = '" + char + "', reversed = '" + reversed + "'");
    reversed = char + reversed
  }
  return reversed
}

console.log(reverse('hello world'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This script :

```
 reversed = char + reversed
```

is prepending the char in the string. So though 'h' is first in the iteration it will be put in the last part of the final concatenated string.